# java RMI and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I have read the basics about rmi, and i think that I am ready to develop my first application, can i use eclipse for testing my rmi app?How?
Also i want some informations for the server side app,(i think that it must run on a glassfish or tomcat server,am I right?)

sorry for my  english and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do everything you need to do for RMI from eclipse.  Don't need any particular server-side infrastructure.  Suggest following the trail:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html